# Color as a third variable in scatter plot for Python 3.5.2

Tags: python-3.x, scatter-plot

I have looked for the answer everywhere and nothing works for me.

In Python 2.7, I used to do `scatter(x,y,c=z,cmap='jet')` as a basic example to colorize the points according to the z variable.

Problem is, this thing doesn't work anymore with Python 3.5.2, which gives the following error message:

> "ValueError: Color array must be two-dimensional"

I tried some solutions written here and there, like:

```
cmap = P.matplotlib.cm.jet 
norm = P.matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1) 
scatter(x,y,c=z,cmap=cmap,norm=norm)
```

but this doesn't work.

Anyone got a tip?

Comment: [Accoring to the docs](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) the color array `c` doesn't need to be two-dimensional. Please support a [verifiable example that gives that error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).